# Copy .jtl file from Jenkins workspace to other folder

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, blazemeter

Here is my requirement,
I am using Jenkins - Blazemeter plugin. When the blazemeter test finishes, I am downloading the JTL file on the Jenkins machine. Now I want to copy the jtl file from the Jenkins workspace to other folder. The problem I am facing is that every time Jenkins makes a folder with a unique alphanumeric value which cannot be ascertained during the run to write another job to copy the jtl file from the folder to other location.

In the Jenkins Console Log I get the below text

```
[2018-03-31 23:22:07]: Check if the test is still running. Time passed since start: 1 minutes.
[2018-03-31 23:23:12]: No errors/failures while validating CIStatus: setting SUCCESS
[2018-03-31 23:23:17]: Saving jtl report **D:\PSST\Projects\Keurig\blazeresult\r-v3-5abfca741c71f**
[2018-03-31 23:23:17]: Trying to get functional summary from server
[2018-03-31 23:23:17]: Trying to get aggregate summary from server
```

Now I want to pick the path in the above starred line and feed it to the next job where I want to copy the JTL file from the folder to other location.

Please help

Comment: How do you copy it? Why can't you use `WORKSPACE` system variable Jenkins provides? Not enough details to answer

Comment: What type of job are you using? Freestyle or Pipeline? I can see that there is a variable called 'jtlpath' in the documentation, have that been tried? [Link: https://github.com/jenkinsci/blazemeter-plugin/wiki/Using-Job-DSL#since-v30-with-new-api-key]

Comment: Its a freestyle project. Let me try the variable.

Comment: I tried as below, but the jtl path is not picking-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test>echo ${jtlpath} 
${jtlpath}

Comment: You ar e using batch (Windows) command to view the path, the command would be echo %jtlpath%. Can you try?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Jenkins if you want to copy results of a build you can use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

> Adds a build step to copy artifacts from another project.The plugin lets you specify which build to copy artifacts from (e.g. the last successful/stable build, by build number, or by a build parameter). You can also control the copying process by filtering the files being copied, specifying a destination directory within the target project, etc. Click the help icon on each field to learn the details, such as selecting Maven or multiconfiguration projects or using build parameters. You can also copy from the workspace of the latest completed build of the source project, instead of its artifacts.

[image]

Choose in Atrifacts to copy `*.jtl` and choose you Target Directory